# video over miracast/dlna dongle and sound over bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, dlna

I have Miracast/DLNA/AirPlay dongle. I connect it to the projector via HDMI and watch movies ok. But at night I want to watch cinema with earphones. ATM I have to sit next to the projector so the cord would reach it.

Is there any software for Android/Ubuntu/Osx 10.11 that would mirror screen (send video) over dongle, but send sound over Bluetooth?..

Thank you in advance

**Update:**

For OsX I tried [recommended dlna clients](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335/how-can-i-make-my-mac-a-dlna-server-and-or-client): Plex, Servio, PS3Media - all three streams both video and audio to dongle, playing system sound on bluetooth.

For Android I tried [AllConnect](https://www.google.ie/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjgo_GEgvvRAhWqJcAKHaNeD7cQFggZMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dcom.tuxera.streambels%26hl%3Den&usg=AFQjCNE0Q6rdMg2rLjGjL8oPrPxH0Q8Yiw&bvm=bv.146094739,d.ZGg) and several other players, that I erased and can't recall their names even.

**General for me: software that streams video to dongle, streams audio as well, ignoring connected Bluetooth speakers**

Comment: On most OSs if you connect a set of Bluetooth headphones you have the option of setting the speakers as them this should even work when you are mirroring to the projector but you may have to turn the projector volume to 0.

Comment: I could not find any mirroring software that would work for mac or android over DLNA/Miracast. DLNA "players" ignore my bluetooth speakers

Answer (score 0):

If you use [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) and set the streaming source to screen:// and stream to a live streaming media such as mms://127.0.0.1:1234 this should stream your desktop video only - not impacting any audio to Bluetooth connection. If you then set your media player to full screen you should be good to go. *I am not 100% sure that this is currently implemented on Android.*

VLC is free, gratis, open source & cross platform.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes - I tried setting up VLC streaming and failed. I `nmap`ed my dongle it listens on 53,80, 7000 and 43152 ports - of course I tried all them, along with 1234